# Meaning of -berg suffix in German city names

Tags: suffix, place-name

Knowing that Berg means mountain, I always assumed that cities such as Wittenberg, Wittenberge, and Perleberg (which is also my married last name) were named for nearby mountains. But there ARE no mountains in that part of Germany. Is it possible they're named for nearby hilltops? Or could -berg be an old misspelling of -burg?

Comment: Inside a large flat area (the "holy Roman Empire's sandbox"), *anything* higher might count as a mountain. ;) Wikipedia says, the highest elevation above ground in Perleberg would be 16m.

Comment: I can confirm, "Berg" is indeed still commonly used as a word for *any* elevation in northern Germany (yup, even if it's only one single meter above ground! - if the speaker feels like it).

Comment: Indeed this resonates with me a resident of Kansas, USA!

Comment: In my childhood days, we often met to play at the „Beeke-Berg“, the highest elevation anyway near my village, which was just some heap of dirt about 500m away from the village, maybe 1.5m in height. Everybody called it „Berg“, although everybody knew it was not a real mountain. We knew that because only 8 km away, there were real mountains, the highest reaching 92m above sea level!So, just because you see no mountains doesn’t mean there are no mountains - it depends on what you are used to.

Comment: If I read about „Perleberg“ in the German Wikipedia, it definitely matches my north-German definition of a mountainous landscape...  In my city (Hannover), there are different parts named after the defining „mountains“, like the Schneiderberg (5m higher than its surroundings) and the Mühlenberg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to german [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Berg) the word *Berg* has it origin in the proto-germanic word ***bergaz** which means *Höhe* (elevation). So in the beginning (9th century) an elevation in the terrain could be named "-berg".

And in the case of Perleberg apparently the elevation of 16 m was sufficient to call it "-berg".

The word *Burg* has it [origin](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Burg) in the meaning of *bergende Umgebung* (protective environment). Note that *bergen* means *recover*.

And in deed, both words have a relationship in its origins in the meaning of *Geborgenheit* (security):

> Berg = schützende, bergende Höhe = protective elevation
>   Burg = befestigte Höhe, befestigter Ort = fortified elevation or place

Comment: And everything, I would suppose, related to some protoindoeuropean *bereg (or the like), see also slavonic bereg / brjag / breg / бряг for "coast" (which is the elevated piece of land bordering a stream, lake, or sea). But the common root lies several thousand years in the past.

Comment: This is also true for *Gebirge* (*mountains, mountain range*). In the east of Austria, there is a chain of hills, called *Leitha**gebirge*** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitha_Mountains It is about 30 km long, and at its highest point only 484 m above sea level (which is only about 300 m above the surrounding areas).

Comment: I believe this confirms my intuition that the -berg in Perleberg does refer to an elevated piece of land. "Promoting" any height of land to the status of "Berg" in that part of Germany resonates with me as a "flatlander." The same thing happens where I live in Kansas, USA. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

English *hill* translates into German **Hügel** but unlike in English speaking countries there are no cities, not even even villages but **two** named *-hügel* (*Birkenhügel* and *Königshügel*) and none *… am … Hügel*.

Perhaps because **Hügel** usually don't have a unique name in Germany. Or maybe because the most known *Hügel* are **der Maulwurfshügel**, **der Idiotenhügel** and **der Grabhügel**. (All these aren't good places to live at.)

What you see from time to time are hamlets on hills called **-höhe**.

All other places promoted their hills to be mountains a long time ago.

In addition, *-berg* is not a misspelling of *-burg* but as mountain tops are good places to build a *Burg*, there often existed a *X-burg* on top of a town named *X-berg*. This isn't the case for *Perleberg*, though, that *Burg* was named *Gänseburg* after the *Gans* family.

Comment: + for the *Idiotenhügel*, but still the question remains unanswered if -berg in toponyms could be a derivative of -burg.

Comment: I've added a paragraph addressing that.

Comment: *Hügelsheim* kommt von *Hugo*, nicht *Hügel*. Die anderen beiden habe ich ergänzt.

Comment: Sowohl *Hügelsheim* (bei Rastatt in Baden) als auch *Hügelheim* (Ortsteil von Müllheim im Markgräflerland) haben ihren Namen tatsächlich nicht vom *Hügel* (obwohl es bei beiden Ansiedlungen genug davon hätte), sondern vom Vornamen *Hugo*.

Comment: Dass keiner auf einem *Hügel* wohnen will, stimmt wohl nicht ganz - beweist wohl die Familie Krupp mit ihrer *Villa Hügel* in Essen.

Comment: Eigennamen sollen ja gerade was besonderes sein. Und *Villa Berg* war schon vergeben.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of similarity with Slavic languages word "breg" or " bereg".
"Breg" actually means "hill", not mountain ("planina").
In the places with a lot of mountains, there is fairly clear distinction between mountain and hill.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is translating "Berg" with "mountain", which is sometimes correct and sometimes isn't. Don't think "mountain". Think "iceberg" (only without the ice). Those can be either very big or rather small.